# How can I copy a png image to clipboard in order to paste it in other app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a custom keyboard and I want to be able to copy the button image to clipboard (it's a png image). I've already tried something like `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = UIImage(named: "dMk87zJ.png")` when the button is pressed, but it doesn't work. I was only able to accomplish that with text. What am I doing wrong ?
  [image: Application Test]

Comment: make sure that your "UIImage(named: "dMk87zJ.png")" actually returns the image, and not nil. This works just fine in my app.

Comment: it's not nil and it's not working. how did you do ?

Comment: Where are you trying to paste the image into?  Have you verified that `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image` is not nil after setting?

Comment: I managed to make it work. I had to set the attribute RequestOpenAccess to YES in info.plist. After that, I had to enable full access in my keyboard preference.

Comment: Hey man I am actually working with that same exact demo code and had the same question. Is there anyway I could take a look at how you fixed this?

Comment: sure. i can send you the code if you still need it. @jeremykrall

Comment: @andrefurquin i'm also facing the same problem as your faced. And i also give the RequestOpenAccess to YES in the .plist file and allow the  full access in my keyboard preference. But it not working. Can u suggest any thing??

Answer (score 7):

Please **use below** code for copy and paste images.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

Its perfect work in all apps which allow paste functionality. Especially Notes app.

For UTI types use [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

**Don't use** below code

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = image;
```

**I face issue with Notes app with this line of code to copy png image**

Comment: HI @Amit Bhavsar I tried that. It set the data to the UIPasteboard. But when I clicked on the image in the simulator it doesn't show the image copied clipboard or when I long press on the input view not showing the paste option. How to do that?

Comment: Hi @Ramakrishna please try in a device, you can test with iMessage, Email, Notes App in a device. 
Input view must support image paste support to display paste option. Default input views like UITextView and UITextField do not support paste support other than plain text.

Comment: Hoo ok. Thanks for the reply. I will try That. Actually, I'm trying to paste that in a UITextview. So, that's why  I'm not getting any paste option.

Comment: What I have to do if I want to paste it in the input view?

Comment: Your answer worked for me well. But it not showing the "COPIED" in the clipboard when I clicking on that image.

Comment: Hi @Amit Bhavsar did you have any idea about loading the videos into the custom keyboard?

Comment: Please, **use below** code for copy and paste videos (mp4).
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.mpeg-4"];

Comment: I have updated link for UTI type in my answer, please refer it for more UTI types.

Comment: I tried that code but I'm having this message "expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: step over. The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation".  And I did some research on it and it says "saving it into NSData and then converting it into base64 format goes out of size and then compiler throws the issue."